# Postgresql - update or delete a value from a nested jsonb element

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Is there a way to delete/update a nested json key object (not array)
for example the following json:

```
{
  "top": {
    "nested": {
       "leaf": 1
    }
  }  
}
```

how would I delete/update the leaf element?

I tried

`SELECT jsonb '{"top": {"nested": {"leaf" : 1}}' - '{top,nested,leaf}'`

but no luck

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use the `#-` operator, not `-`:

```
SELECT jsonb '{"top": {"nested": {"leaf" : 1}}}' #- '{top,nested,leaf}';
┌─────────────────────────┐
│        ?column?         │
├─────────────────────────┤
│ {"top": {"nested": {}}} │
└─────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

---

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

- `-` (given a `text` argument): Delete key/value pair or string element from left operand. Key/value pairs are matched based on their key value.
- `-` (given an `int` argument): Delete the array element with specified index (Negative integers count from the end). Throws an error if top level container is not an array.
- `#-`: Delete the field or element with specified path (for JSON arrays, negative integers count from the end)

Comment: How does it know what table to perform that one THOUGH

Comment: @ennth: what do you mean? If you had a table `t` with a jsonb column `j` you would do `SELECT j -# '{to,remove}' FROM t`.